# Regex Google sheets match dates that have different number of digits for day and month

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

In google sheets I would like to be able to extract dates from a text cell. I found a solution in [RegEx get last match of a date format from string inside a Google Sheets cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092799/regex-get-last-match-of-a-date-format-from-string-inside-a-google-sheets-cell)  but it doesn't take into account that my dates are not formatted equally.
They might have 1 or 2 digits for the day, then 1 or 2 for the month and 2 or 4 for the year.

I have adapted the solution from above to look for multple digits using d{1, }:

`"(?:.+)(\d{1,}-\d{1,}-\d{2,})"` but if the day has 2 digits the first digit falls off

"1-8-2018 en 1-2-2019" results in -> 1-2-2019
"26-3-19 en 23-4-2019" results in -> 3-4-2019
"1-1-20 of 8-2-20 en dan 12-10-20"  -> 2-10-20<>

It seems to work fine for month and year but not for the day, how do I solve this?

Bonus question:
Mostly there are 2 dates in the cell sometimes 3 maybe more in future. I would like to be able to select which of the dates is returned. It is now selectingt the last date. Is there a way to count the number of matches from the beginning and then choose one?

Comment: Can you share the sheet publicly or a copy of it to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```golang
^(?:.*?(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KY0MSt/1).  This will select the second date in each string due to the `{2}` limiting quantifier at the end. Adjust the limit number to the one you need.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (used to group patterns to be quantified here)

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (`*?` is non-greedy)
  - `(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)` - Group 1 (the actual output): one or two digits, `-`, one or two digits, `-`, two digits and then an optional chunk of two digits
- `){2}` - end of the non-capturing group, match two occurrences